# Being able to edit text of copied layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs4, photoshop-cs4

I have a layer in `Photoshop CS4` which is basically a button with some text on it, but I'm wondering how to I go about copying this layer with all the effects etc (exact copy) and then being able to edit the text on the copied version?

I tried a `copy merged` but wasn't able to edit the text on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this question correctly. You can copy the layer by pressing Ctrl+J then click on the layer that you ant to edit the text on, then press the text editing icon on the left sidebar and edit your text.

Comment: That seemed to work, however it places the new layer right on top of the one it copied; when I try and move it all it does is seem to move the text from the new layer.

Comment: What you could do from there, is on the right hand side of the program you should see a list of your layers, you could try clicking on one of the layers and dragging it down under the other ones. The layers go in order with what you see on the top is the layer thats going to be on top of all the other layers.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I got confused.... I want to copy multiple layers; basically it consists of the button and text layers.

Comment: Click on each layer and hold down Ctrl and click on all of the layers you want to make a copy of and once you have selected them all, then press Ctrl+J, if you would like to merge layers together, do the same thing by holding Ctrl and clicking on the layers you want to merge together and press Ctrl+E